# How to access properties on AppDelegate from classes owned by it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a simple OS X app which so far is structured like so:

- The main business logic is in `AppDelegate.m`
- There are 2 `ViewControllers` with xibs that the `AppDelegate` owns and presents in a window

I sometimes need to access properties on AppDelegate from the ViewControllers, which I'm doing like this:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.someProperty = someValue;
```

This "feels" hacky. Is it a proper pattern or is this really dumb?

Two alternative architectures I came up with were:

1. To use delegation and define some kind of "UI Delegate" protocol in the VCs and make the AppDelegate conform to it
2. To have the VCs post notifications that the AppDelegate listens to

The first feels tangled and dirty, the second feels unreliable.

What is the proper pattern here? How should VCs owned by the `AppDelegate` access its properties?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AppDelegate *app = [NSApp delegate];
```

Instead of this

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a category on `NSObject` that will allow you to get your instance of the `AppDelegate` from any object in your project.

```
@interface NSObject (AppDelegate)

- (AppDelegate *)appDelegate;

@end
```

You can then include the category in your project .pch file so that it's available everywhere.